# WLAN module compatible with ArduiMU V3+

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, communication

Current I use my [ArduiMU V3+](https://store.3drobotics.com/products/arduimu-v3) with a Bluetooth Mate (from Sparkfun) but I've got a lot of connection problems with it.

I'm looking for a better solution involving WLAN and am wondering whether there are compatible modules?

[image]